# Windows 10 microphone not working version 1803

Tags: windows, microphone, windows-10-v1803

I formatted my computer from Windows settings a few weeks ago. Since then, my microphone does not work. I switched all privacy settings for mic ON and I re-installed Realtek a few times.

I thought it might be a physical problem, so I bought a USB adapter for microphone and audio. Still doesn't work.

I don't know what to do, please help.

If you need further information, please ask me in comments.

Comment: In addition to turning the *microphone* on, you must enable access by the *specific application*, e.g. Cortana or Edge. See the *Privacy* settings.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik He mentioned he switched all privacy settings on...

Comment: Pictures of relevant control panel settings would clear up that confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem, and then I tried to solve the matter by disabling the antivirus tool, which gets me the problem solved. I guess the antivirus tool was restricting the audio service to work on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Audio Services gets blocked by the Premium Antiviruses. SO try disabling it and check. Or else simply use the troubleshooting by Windows which is really effective in finding the exact problem. Then fix it manually.